# Abstract class as ref parameter - compiler error

Tags: c#, abstract-class, ref

I have this simple sample on VS2010:

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AbsClass absClass = new ConClass();
            // I have tried this also and the error is different:
            // ConClass absClass = new ConClass();
            absClass.Id = "first";
            Console.WriteLine(absClass.Id);
            MyMethod(ref absClass);  // <<- ERROR.
            Console.WriteLine(absClass.Id);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public void MyMethod(ref AbsClass a)
        {
            a.Id = "new";
        }
    }

    public abstract class AbsClass
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class ConClass : AbsClass { }
}
```

I would like to know why this cannot build right.

Comment: What's the compiler error that you get?

Comment: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'ConsoleApplication1.Program.MyMethod(ref ConsoleApplication1.AbsClass)'" - kinda says it all, no?

Comment: @Femaref's answer is correct. The reason the commented-out version (with ConClass) doesn't work is that the type of variable passed as an argument to a ref parameter must match exactly to the type of the parameter. This ensures that any assignments in the method will work OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make your `MyMethod` static:

```
    public static void MyMethod(ref AbsClass a)
    {
        a.Id = "new";
    }
```

The problem isn't the abstract class, the "problem" is the static `Main` method. Static methods don't have an instance, and as such, can't call instance methods.

[msdn on static classes and static members](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

Comment: Yes, right.   It runs now as static.   But why ?  Or, please, some link to official documentation to read about it ?

Comment: Sorry... I was not seen your comment below the code.   Do you mean if I put it on a non Main static method original code will run fine ?

Comment: I added a link, but in a nutshell, the reason is already in the post. The `Main` method is `static`, and as such, isn't associated with a particular instance of the class `Program`. Resulting of that, it can only call other methods that don't rely on an instance of `Program` as well.

Comment: No, it doesn't - the `Main` method is the entry point for your application, the runtime looks for a static `Main` method in your code. If it doesn't find one, you'll get an exception and the program won't run.

Comment: I think understand it.  
For future readers I will put a code in the question that runs fine with MyMethod without static clause (inside a manager class).
Thanks Femaref.

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make your `MyMethod` method static:

```
public static MyMethod(ref AbsClass a)
{
    a.Id = "new";
}
```

Or preferrably, create an instance of the `Program` class, and call `MyMethod` from that instance:

```
Program p = new Program();
p.MyMethod(ref abs);
```

The reason why the first method works is because the `Main` method is marked static, and isn't tied to an instance of the `Program` class. The .NET Framework CLR searches through your assembly for a static method named `Main` that takes an array of `String`, and makes that function the entry point. You'll notice that a lot of tutorials and even MSDN code samples mark the `Program` class with the static keyword, which is considered best practice when all of the methods in a class contain only static methods.

The reason why the second method works, and why this method is preferred, is because you defined `MyMethod` to be an **instance method**. Basically, you need an instance of an object in order to execute an instance method; the `new` keyword creates an instance of a specified type. Static methods can be called without an instance of an object, but also cannot access any non-static instance members (properties, private/public variables, etc). Generally, you want to avoid static methods and classes unless you must implement a utility class, utilize extension methods, or provide helper methods.